# How to prevent a user from using YouTube while connected to my network

Tags: ip, firewall, dns

i need to restrick specific user from using youtube and other socialmedia during job time

Comment: Please add a comprehensive description of your network and the router/firewall models to your question. Note that consumer-grade hardware, devices without optional, paid vendor support and product recommendations are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

The general answer to this question is that you need equipment (gateway/firewall) or software (software on the user device) that will prevent/restrict access to desired categories of websites according to user profile or device identifier (MAC address etc.).

There are many options for doing this (as well as some subscription services that combine software and/or hardware options) and recommendations are off topic here. If you already have equipment or software designed for this kind of feature, the manufacturer will be able to provide support or you can ask specific questions about the design of the network to accommodate the feature/platform but questions about layer 4 or higher (Transport layer) are off topic as well.